# Google Cloud DNS :: Multiple domains in one zone

Tags: domains, google-cloud-dns

I managed to upload my BIND zone files to GC DNS, but not /etc/named.conf. Which I do not need to, but I want to have multiple domains with one zone.

How do I do that with GC DNS? In other words: how do I add multiple domains to a zone?

Comment: I kind of solved this problem by making identical zones, one per domain. This meant getting 4 slightly different NSs, but that was not the kind of redundancy I was waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have provided in the comment is the correct one. 
You can use the same Cloud DNS zone for subdomains (eg. video.yoursite.com, photos.yoursite.com).

If you are having different DNS name suffix (yoursite.com, secondsite.com) you need to create a separate DNS zone.

You can check [Cloud DNS Managed Zones](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#general_dns_concepts) for more info.

Comment: And sorry/please, I did read the documentation. To no avail.

Comment: I already scripted the replacement of the complete zones with each domain, but I fail to see this is the correct solution.

Comment: I assumed you have read the documentation, just wanted to point out where it is mentioning Managed Zones.
For each domain you have you will need different Cloud DNS zone and this is by design.

Comment: To me, this seems a bad design. I think what I want is very common, e.g. to facilitate vhosts. Can you tell me what the rationale behind this design?

Comment: As mentioned in (https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/), a managed zone is the container for all of your DNS records that share the same domain name. 
GCP Cloud DNS are not the same as DNS zones on host companies like GoDaddy, it is a different concept. In a Cloud DNS you can define an A record that can point to a VM that you manage and you can upgrade that VM. 
If you wish to host several domains in one IP, you can add vhosts in your web server. This is how to do it in Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: I know vhosts, that is one of the reasons I wanted to have multiple domains per zone.